# Collections and Naturally ordering a Map<Long, Map<String, String>>

Tags: java, dictionary, guava

I'm having trouble with the more intricate map; for a standard `Map<Long, String>`, I would do something like:

```
Ordering<Long> valueComparator = Ordering.natural().onResultOf(Functions.forMap(myMap));
Map<Long, String> orderedMap = ImmutableSortedMap.copyOf(myMap, valueComparator);
```

But I can't seem to get it to like `Map<Long, Map<String, String>>`, still ordered by Long.  Maybe I'm missing something? Below doesn't work...

```
Ordering<Long> valueComparator = Ordering.natural().onResultOf(Functions.forMap(myOtherMap));
Map<Long, Map<String, String>> orderedMyOtherMap = ImmutableSortedMap.copyOf(myOtherMap,valueComparator);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example isn't doing what you seem to be saying it's doing. It's creating a map that's ordered by the `String` values corresponding to each `Long` key. If you wanted to just order by the keys, you'd just do:

```
ImmutableSortedMap<Long, String> orderedMap = ImmutableSortedMap.copyOf(myMap);
```

The same thing would work for a `Map<Long, Map<String, String>>`. The reason what you're trying to do doesn't work is that a `Map<String, String>` is not `Comparable`, so there is no natural ordering for it.

As an aside, you *may* want to consider using a `Table<Long, String, String>` rather than a `Map<Long, Map<String, String>>`. There's even a [TreeBasedTable](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeBasedTable.html) that will store the row and column keys in sorted order.